# Parse setting explicit type using REST

Tags: rest, parse-platform

I know you can set a Date field explicitly like so:

```
"date_brewed":{
    "__type":"Date",
    "iso":"2009-10-15T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

But is there anyway to explicitly set the column type of 'Number' using REST?  For instance, I'd like to set the column 'batch_size' to a Number instead of a string but when POST'ing via rest it keeps getting created as a string type column.

Answer (score 0):

Meh, this was more of a Perl issue than a Parse issue.

What I had to do to tell Perl to treat the number like an actual number was to add a zero to the value.  :/